# File browser using pyqt4 in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

I am trying to create desktop app. I have created a button using pyqt4 designer.Then converted .ui to .py file. Button which i have created should work as file picker. I am finding difficult to add file browser to that.Can any one help me regarding this.

**Code i tried**

> ```
> def setupUi(self, WizardPage):
>         WizardPage.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("WizardPage"))
>         WizardPage.resize(636, 486)
>         self.horizontalLayoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(WizardPage)
>         self.groupBox = QtGui.QGroupBox(self.horizontalLayoutWidget)
>         self.groupBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("groupBox"))
>         self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.groupBox)
> ```

```
def retranslateUi(self, WizardPage):
    WizardPage.setWindowTitle(_translate("WizardPage", "WizardPage", None))
    self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("WizardPage", "SOURCE", None))
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("WizardPage", "Click Me!", None))
    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.pushButton_Clicked)

def pushButton_Clicked(self, WizardPage):
    filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self)
```

Please guide me where i am going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, ***never*** directly edit the .py file created by `pyuic`. Instead, import it into your main program, or (my preferred method, makes you more productive) use the `uic` module (imported from `PyQt` with `from PyQt4 import uic`.) `ui = uic.loadUi('example.ui')` will import the UI file.

However, in resolution of your problem you need to change some things.

```
openfile = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self) # Filename line
f = open(openfile, 'r') # New line
data = f.read() # New line
```

Comment: Thanks I got it.then how do i make use of buttons which i created using pyQT??

Comment: If you're using PyQt5 this shoul work:

`openfile = PyQt5.QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self)`