# How to open a file browser dialog with PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-import

I would like to use this line `QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self)` to open a file dialogue such as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140428/file-browser-using-pyqt4-in-python) but from PyQt5 rather than PyQt4. My import statement currently is `from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, uic, QtGui`.

What am I doing wrong?

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "H:/4-Programming/OpenTester/OpenTester.py", line 136, in MenuNew
>       fileToOpen = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self)
>   AttributeError: module 'PyQt5.QtGui' has no attribute 'QFileDialog'

Comment: line 136  -> fileToOpen = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self)

Comment: Perfect thank you!

Comment: @S.Nick it would be better if you post it as an answer :)